# Why am I not getting the value pairs for all three sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to return all value pairs from three sequences, however I am only getting a single value pair for the first sequence. Does anyone know what happens?. The example sequences are "ALLKAIIAI", "AHHAKKAKLLA", "APPALLAIIKAMMA", see it in the code bellow:

```
def ComputeSeqs():

    input_seq = ["ALLKAIIAI", "AHHAKKAKLLA", "APPALLAIIKAMMA"]

    for sequence in input_seq:

        ANDN920101={'A':4.35,'L':4.17,'R':4.38,'K':4.36,'N':4.75,
        'M':4.52,'D':4.76,'F':4.66,'C':4.65,'P':4.44,
        'Q':4.37,'S':4.50,'E':4.29,'T':4.35,'G':3.97,
        'W':4.70,'H':4.63,'Y':4.60,'I':3.95,'V':3.95}

        ARGP820101={'A':0.61,'L':1.53,'R':0.60,'K':1.15,'N':0.06,
        'M':1.18,'D':0.46,'F':2.02,'C':1.07,'P':1.95,
        'Q':0.0,'S':0.05,'E':0.47,'T':0.05,'G':0.07,
        'W':2.65,'H':0.61,'Y':1.88,'I':2.22,'V':1.32}

        aaindex_values = []
        
        aaindex_listT = [ANDN920101, ARGP820101]

        for i in aaindex_listT:

            a_a = ((sequence.count("A") * i["A"])) / len(sequence)
            c_c = ((sequence.count("C") * i["C"])) / len(sequence)
            d_d = ((sequence.count("D") * i["D"])) / len(sequence)
            e_e = ((sequence.count("E") * i["E"])) / len(sequence)
            f_f = ((sequence.count("F") * i["F"])) / len(sequence)
            g_g = ((sequence.count("G") * i["G"])) / len(sequence)
            h_h = ((sequence.count("H") * i["H"])) / len(sequence)
            i_i = ((sequence.count("I") * i["I"])) / len(sequence)
            k_k = ((sequence.count("K") * i["K"])) / len(sequence)
            l_l = ((sequence.count("L") * i["L"])) / len(sequence)
            m_m = ((sequence.count("M") * i["M"])) / len(sequence)
            n_n = ((sequence.count("N") * i["N"])) / len(sequence)
            p_p = ((sequence.count("P") * i["P"])) / len(sequence)
            q_q = ((sequence.count("Q") * i["Q"])) / len(sequence)
            r_r = ((sequence.count("R") * i["R"])) / len(sequence)
            s_s = ((sequence.count("S") * i["S"])) / len(sequence)
            t_t = ((sequence.count("T") * i["T"])) / len(sequence)
            v_v = ((sequence.count("V") * i["V"])) / len(sequence)
            w_w = ((sequence.count("W") * i["W"])) / len(sequence)
            y_y = ((sequence.count("Y") * i["Y"])) / len(sequence)

            aaindex_comp = round(((a_a + c_c + d_d + e_e + f_f + g_g + h_h + i_i + k_k + l_l + m_m + n_n + p_p + q_q + r_r + s_s + t_t + v_v + w_w + y_y) / 20),3)
            aaindex_values.append(aaindex_comp)

        return aaindex_values

print(ComputeSeqs())
```

Comment: Take `aaindex_values = []` out of the loop. You're clearing the list for each sequence.

Comment: And `return aaindex_values` shouldn't be in the loop. You're returning after processing the first sequence.

Comment: OK, but how I can get the results in this format?: [0.209, 0.071], [0.219, 0.046], [0.215, 0.064]

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `aaindex_values` before the loop, and return it after the loop.

You're never creating nested lists for results of summing the multipliers from each dictionary in `aaindex_listT`. This is easiest done using a list comprehension. And you can loop over the dictionary and use `sum()` rather than creating 26 different variables.

```
def ComputeSeqs():

    input_seq = ["ALLKAIIAI", "AHHAKKAKLLA", "APPALLAIIKAMMA"]

    ANDN920101={'A':4.35,'L':4.17,'R':4.38,'K':4.36,'N':4.75,
                'M':4.52,'D':4.76,'F':4.66,'C':4.65,'P':4.44,
                'Q':4.37,'S':4.50,'E':4.29,'T':4.35,'G':3.97,
                'W':4.70,'H':4.63,'Y':4.60,'I':3.95,'V':3.95}

    ARGP820101={'A':0.61,'L':1.53,'R':0.60,'K':1.15,'N':0.06,
                'M':1.18,'D':0.46,'F':2.02,'C':1.07,'P':1.95,
                'Q':0.0,'S':0.05,'E':0.47,'T':0.05,'G':0.07,
                'W':2.65,'H':0.61,'Y':1.88,'I':2.22,'V':1.32}
    aaindex_listT = [ANDN920101, ARGP820101]

    aaindex_values = []
        
    for sequence in input_seq:
        aaindex_comp = [sum(sequence.count(key) * value for key, value in i.items()) / len(sequence) for i in aaindex_listT]
        aaindex_values.append(aaindex_comp)

    return aaindex_values

print(ComputeSeqs())
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it work perfect. Best regards